# How mapping various types with a single instance using Ninject?

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject

I have this:

```
public class DbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext, IDbContext
{
}
```

My Ninject configuration:

```
public override void Load()
{
    Bind<IDbContext>().To<DbContext>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultConnectionString"]);
}
```

So, How I get the same instance of `DbContext` in another class like:

```
public class ExampleClass()
{
   ...

   public ExampleClass(DbContext myDbContextDependency)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

**Update 1:**

`IDbContext` is my *UnitOfWork pattern*, it lives in my *Domain Layer*:

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

And I need `DbContext` to use in my BaseRepository:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity
{
   ...

   //I'm using DbContext here:
   protected BaseRepository()
   {
      this.DbSet = DbContext.Set(typeof(TEntity));
   }

   //and here:
   public virtual void Edit(TEntity entity)
   {
      this.DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious. If you reuse the same context throughout the whole request, where do you call `SaveChanges`?

Comment: You should probably change the `DbContext` class you created to a different name as to avoid naming conflicts. I see you're using the full namespace name for EF's `DbContext`, but for future maintainer's sake, use a different class name.

Comment: @Omar thanks Omar, I'll consider it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using the Service Locator of Ninject and took back the instance of `DbContext`:

```
public class ExampleClass()
{
    protected DbContext DbContext
    {
        get
        {
                                                                        //Here I do the trick I wanted
            return DependencyResolverFactory.Instance.Get<IDbContext>() as DbContext;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should inject an `IDbContext`, not a `DbContext`:

```
public class ExampleClass()
{
   ...

   public ExampleClass(IDbContext myDbContextDependency)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```